Does Seq2Seq model work for spelling correction? If yes, Why i am getting it wrong?
I am using seq2seq model for predicting or correcting spellings for the product names, I do have dataset of product names with their misspelled and corrected versions(they do contain some special chars too). I have trained that data on few epochs and see some output. But i am giving the user input, it isn't predicting as expected.
Then, after training the model and using this code:
for seq_index in range(1, 50):
    input_seq = encoder_input_data[seq_index : seq_index + 1]
    decoded_sentence = decode_sequence(input_seq)
    print("-")
    print("Input sentence:", input_texts[seq_index]) #Print input sequence with char!
    print("Decoded sentence:", decoded_sentence)

I have got good outputs like:
Input sentence: Fluidic WorkCation
Decoded sentence: Fluidic Worksation

Input sentence: Li@uid Handler, Biomek FXp DuaO
Decoded sentence: Liquid Handler, Biomek NXp Mult

Then if i try to give a user input and let the model predict, i do get some text like this
Input sentence: system
Decoded sentence: 'Gamma Counter/Rotor - Water Machine System, Automated Parallell\n'

which is way far on what it has learnt, but i have used the same code of encoder and decoder model. I want to know whether this seq2seq model will work for these scenarios or not first.
